# I need to pass a GQL query request in Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I need to get a particular `Entity` from my table here is the python GQL query.

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE id='12345'
```

What is the Java version of this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Query query = new Query("table1");
query.addFilter("id", FilterOperator.EQUAL, "12345");
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(query);
Entity customer = pq.asSingleEntity();
```

This did the trick for me